# ORing lxml xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

What would be the correct syntax for the following?

```
trailer_node.find('''
    data_file[@role="source"]/
    attribute[@name="image.burned_forced_narrative.locale" or @name="hello"]
 ''')
```

Current I get `InvalidPredicate` error from lxml

Comment: `.find()` isn't `.xpath()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.find()` if you want XPath syntax. Use `.xpath()` instead.